# Does parent:: automatically determine class and object invoke context?

Tags: php, class, object, parent

In first case we called function in object context. In second case we have class context.
Does parent:: work like this and self simultaneously depending on the context?

```
class par_parent{
    private $var='value1';
    private static $val='value2';
    public function call(){
        var_dump('Object '.$this->var);
    }
    public static function staticCall(){
        var_dump('Static '.self::$val);
    }
}

class par_child extends par_parent{
    public function callObj(){
        parent::call();
    }

    public static function callStatic(){
        parent::staticCall();
    }
}



$obj=new par_child();
$obj->callObj();
**//string 'Object value1' (length=13)**
par_child::callStatic();
**//string 'Static value2' (length=13)**
```

Comment: See the PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

Comment: Yes, `parent::` must work on context. Without context, how would it know which class is the parent?

Comment: My question about how parent:: work in class and object context simultaneously like $this-> and self::. And I don't find answer in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parent::` is binded like the `self::` keyword, always sees the context where it have been defined code wise, not from where it's called, so in essence it works like the `self::` keyword. If you need it to work like the `$this` use late static binding provieded `static::`. Consider this example:

```
class A { 
    protected static $v = 'a';
    public static function staticsay() {
        print static::$v;
    }

}
class B extends A { 
    protected static $v = 'b';
    public static function say(){
        print parent::$v;
    }
}
class C extends B { 
    protected static $v = 'c';
    public static function selfsay(){
        print parent::$v;
    }
} 

C::say(); // prints 'a'
C::selfsay(); // prints 'b'
C::staticsay(); // prints 'c'
```

Here we call the `say()` method on `C` it comes from the class `B` so it's `parent::` means `A` and the `A::$v` is 'a' so it prints that.

While the `parent::` in `C` points to the class `B` and it sees it's `$v` as 'b'.

With php 5.3 comes late static binding and the `static::` keyword that lets you access the `static` variables and methods in baseclasses static methods so the `A::staticsay` will see the `$v` from the class `C`.

Comment: But my question about parent::
It work with parent class like $this-> or self:: or maybe like static:: or something other?